# How to make multiple commits Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

after receiving the data from the request, I try to transfer them to the store. but it is not possible to transfer everything at once, only one at a time. how to solve this problem?

```
async loadFines({ commit }, payload) {
commit('setIsTableLoading', true);

try {
  const {
    data: {
      data: fines,
      meta: pagination,
      query: backendQuery,
    },
  } = await this.$axios.get('/fines', { params: payload });

  commit('setFinesList', fines);
  commit('setPagination', pagination);
  commit('setBackendQuery', backendQuery);

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
} finally {
  commit('setIsTableLoading', false);
}}
```

how to make those 3 commits properly?

```
export const mutations = {
  setFinesList(state, payload) {
    state.finesList = payload
  },

  setIsTableLoading(state, payload) {
    state.isTableLoading = payload;
  },

  setPagination(state, payload) {
    state.pagination = payload;
  },

  setLabels(state, payload) {
    state.labels = payload;
  },

  setBackendQuery(state, payload) {
    state.backendQuery = payload;
  }
}
```

Comment: Multiple commits are done this way. What problem do you have with this code?

Comment: @EstusFlask for some unknown reason, the store is not updated. if you leave any one commit, then everything is ok

Comment: Can you share your store file? where the mutation is defined

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem and make sure the question explains it. You ask about the problem that doesn't exist in general and is very specific to your code.

Comment: as a side note i think its better to make an action that commit your mutation, there is no issue here it's the way of doing it, for each property in the state you are modifying you commit a mutation, so you end up with multiple commits and it's normal